# Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update using Mobaxterm

Tags: apt, mobaxterm

I downloaded Mobaxterm to use the a Bash shell. The problem is, I can't compile my C files with "cc -o file file.c". It shows me this :

Command 'cc' not found, but can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install gcc

sudo apt install clang

sudo apt install pentium-builder

sudo apt install tcc
```

But whenever I type these commands it returns me error messages such as :

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev
amd64 4.15.0-29.31
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev
 amd64 4.15.0-29.31
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.
88.162 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
mainuser@DESKTOP-AN5KMJ2:/mnt/c/Users/LEPCDC~1/Desktop$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: Might find better luck in [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Have you also tried to prepend `sudo`before `apt-get update`?

Comment: Follow the suggestion: run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @SouravGhosh & others - this doesn't appear to be an Ubuntu issue. MobaXterm is a MS-Windows program that includes a terminal emulator, an X Server and other, related utilities. `sudo` is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Plugin section of the website and download plugin
 **Gcc, G++ and development tools: the GNU C/C++ compiler and other development tools**.
It'll download a file named **Development.mxt3**
Now go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\` folder and paste the downloaded file here. 
[Copying the plugin file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apZyv.jpg)

Open the application's terminal and by now you'll be able to compile

```
cc -o file file.c
```

and run as follows

```
./file.exe
```

[compile & run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIoux.jpg)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: have you gone through exact procedures as i double checked it now (in windows 10) also and it worked. can you explain what you did ?

Comment: @DanielD i'll mention complete procedures 1- download mobaxterm. 2- download gccc plugin(5th line) from `https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html` . 3- paste the downloaded file in the root/default directory of the mobaxterm executable (mentioned above). 4- close and reopen the applicatio, open treminal and it should work.
hope this helps.